# throw is causing code to crash instead of just exiting

Tags: c++, crash, throw

Beginner programmer here, working in Visual Studio.

```
vector<string> fileParse(vector<string> & inputStrings, string & fileName) {
    ifstream x;
    x.open(fileName);
    cout << "attempting to open file" << endl;
    if (!x.is_open()) {
        cout << "Bad input file name. Input was: " << fileName << endl;
        throw lab0badInput;
    }
    else {
        string temp;
        while (x >> temp) {
            inputStrings.push_back(temp);
        }
        x.close();
    }
    return inputStrings;
}
```

Calling `throw` causes my program to crash instead of throwing the correct value and exiting. Can somebody explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error message when the crash happens?

Comment: Where should the correct value be thrown?  Plz catch your exception in your program and call std::exit()

Comment: Crash == program exiting.

Comment: What is `lab0badInput` ? I mean what's the type, etc.

Comment: @yuriyivaskevych, it's an enumeration.

Comment: If the program doesn't catch the exception it terminates abruptly instead of exiting.

Answer (score -1):

use try and catch block instead :

```
try { /* */ } catch (const std::exception& e) { /* */ }
```